# How to export data from Power BI to Excel file with slicer / filter on it?

Tags: excel, filter, export, powerbi, slicers

Hi i'm new at the Power BI.

I would like to export data from my Power BI dashboard to an excel file. but I faced some problem, the exported data/file doesn't contain the slicer/filter that I choose, it only contain **the result**.

I want the excel file also contain the filter / slicer that I used in the dashboard.
[image: this is my dashboard and I choose some filter on it]

I would like to export data from the dashboard. the data that I want is the whole data (include the filter that I applied and the table) in one excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly export the data with the filter applied and the whole data in the background. You can either export all "underlying data" (all of your data) or the "summarised" data (data with filter/slicer on applied).

See the link below, specifically points 5, 6 + 7 regarding export types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data

Answer (score 0):

You can just export the data or summarized data. I don't think, it is possible to export the data with filters/slicers included.